# Front Door and API Management - Health Check per API

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-front-door

Is there a way to setup a health check for each API under APIM?  We have 4 APIs on the APIM host name but Front Door only has a spot for 1 URL, what if another API is unreachable?

Say the host api.domain.com points to APIM.

Say the microservices hosted are:

```
/profile
/reports
/config
/sales
```

and they are both in 2 regions, East US 2 and Central US.

Front door only lets us check
api.domain.com/profile/health but api.domain.com/sales could be down in one region and we need to shift to the other region.

Comment: Once check any of these documents [1](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/basic-health-checks/) and [2](https://testfully.io/blog/api-health-check-monitoring/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Front Door solution you could use a separate endpoint for each API.  You may also be interested in [API Management availability zone support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/migrate-api-mgt).  You may also want to investigate a way to keep your individual API backends up even if there is a regional issue, assuming they are deployed in multiple locations in Azure.